# Grid is not loading as a item of penal.

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs3

I am trying to load grid in as a item panel with ajax call. My grid is not loading. Can you please help me. This is I am trying because I was not getting scope in ext ajax call.

My code is

```
{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: "Search Result",
                height:500,
                items: [
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: 'XML/1Cohart.xml',
                            scope: this,
                            timeout: global_constants.TIMEOUT,
                            method: "GET", 
                            disableCaching: true,
                            failure: function(response) {
                                utils.showOKErrorMsg(sdisMsg.ajaxRequestFailed);
                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                debugger;
                                var datas = response.responseXML;
                                Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
                                    this.buildField(header);
                                    this.buildColumn(header);
                                }, this);
                                Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function (columnData) {
                                 //debugger;
                                   //this.buildData(columnData);
                                    this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
                                    this.record = [];
                                    for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                                        //debugger;
                                        var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
                                        this.record[i] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
                                    }
                                    this.data.push(this.record);                 
                                }, this);
                                this.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                    fields : this.fields
                                });
                                this.store.loadData(this.data);     
                                var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                                        store: this.store,
                                        flex: 1,
                                        columns: this.columns,
                                        stripeRows: true,
                                        id: 'RID',
                                        autoHeight: true,
                                        //sm: new Ext.grid.Checkbo;xSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
                                        frame: true,
                                    }); 
                            }
                        })
                        ]

            }]
```

Actually I was not getting scope so I placed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: "Search Result",
    height:500,
    items: [{
        xtype : 'GridPanel',
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields : this.fields
        }),
        flex: 1,
        columns: this.columns,
        stripeRows: true,
        id: 'RID',
        autoHeight: true,
        //sm: new Ext.grid.Checkbo;xSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
        frame: true,
        listeners {
            afterRenderer : function(){
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'XML/1Cohart.xml',
                    scope: this,
                    timeout: global_constants.TIMEOUT,
                    method: "GET", 
                    disableCaching: true,
                    failure: function(response) {
                        utils.showOKErrorMsg(sdisMsg.ajaxRequestFailed);
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        debugger;
                        var datas = response.responseXML;
                        Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
                            this.buildField(header);
                            this.buildColumn(header);
                        }, this);
                        Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function (columnData) {
                            //debugger;
                            //this.buildData(columnData);
                            this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
                            this.record = [];
                            for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                                //debugger;
                                var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
                                this.record[i] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
                            }
                            this.data.push(this.record);                 
                        }, this);
                    }); 
                }
            })
        }
    }
    ]
}
```